# Google AI Platform Error: VM: Write access to project 'PROJECT ID' was denied. How to allow write access?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, gcp-ai-platform-notebook, google-ai-platform

On Google **AI Platform Notebook Instance** I get the following error if I try to start/stop or create a new instance: [notebook instance error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryWWm.jpg)

It had been previously working fine and I'm able to start/stop the VM from **compute engine VM instances page** as you can see here: [vm instances](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q57O0.jpg)

After starting the vm from the compute engine page and returning to the Notebook Instance page - the OPEN JUPYTERLAB Option is stuck at settting up proxy.

It seems like I have lost write access to AI Platform API despite being the project owner.

**IAM Roles:**

1. User Account - Project Owner
2. Service Account attacted [Project Id]@appspot.gserviceaccount.com - Project Editor.

Possibly related service account:
3) service-123456789@gcp-sa-notebooks.iam.gserviceaccount.com - AI Platform Notebooks Service Agent.

Comment: Hi, Notebooks API uses the AI Platform Notebooks Service Agent to manage the Notebooks in your user project. Have you modified anything related to this account?. In regards your Account are you Notebooks Admin from Notebooks perspective?

Comment: @gogasca Hey, Its solved now, So i contacted the billing administrator and he got in touch with support team - It was a billing issue and they renenabled the AI Platform API.

Comment: Glad to hear. Thanks for the update

Answer (score 2):

The issue is resolved now. I had contacted the billing administrator who got in touch with google support- It was a billing related issue and they have re-enabled the related API.
Everything is back up now!